# Flask login logs me out of other applications

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, flask-login

I have two instances of the same flask app set up on the same server. The applications run as different users, and look at different datasets. They are configured with two different wsgi files, which are served using apache and mod_wsgi. Each of the wsgi files configures the app to use a different SECRET_KEY.

The issue is that if a user logs into one, the other application immediately logs them out of the other. Is there a setting that is causing them to stomp on each other's login keys?

Answer (score 1):

Set the cookie path different for each application. They are probably fighting over the same cookie.

- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie